# HTML CSS background Image buggy

Tags: html, css

Hello im an very beginner of html/css i made an navigation bar and an footer till yet. So i wanted an background image now but its bugged idk why. I tested a couple of random images but its for every image. Can someone help me pls? Code and Screenshot of the Problem bel[image]ow[image]

I tried background-repeat: no-repeat;
But i am a very beginer so i dont know what to do. I just want an normal background. The details are already described

Comment: with the "*" selector all your DOM elements are getting this background; you probably want "html, body" as selector only! ;-)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* {
 background-image: url(ttt.png);
}
```

The above code means you put every element a background image.

If you just want body with the background image, use below code

```
body {
 background-image: url(ttt.png);
}
```

You also should set something like `background-size` to make the size you want.

[The doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)